# Python: interactive shell, how to write/export to local file

Tags: python, python-2.7

e.g. 
I have a dict.

```
>>> gtf['mykey1']

{'name': {'apple': '20', 'eat': ['Leo', 'Amy', 'Lily', 'Lucy']}
```

I want to save this output to a local file named out.txt.

How should I do this?

I tried

```
%store gtf['mykey1'] > out.txt
```

which did not work.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try just to open a file and write to it:

```
import json

output = open('output.txt', 'w')
stringified_entry = json.dumps(gtf['mykey1'])
output.write(stringified_entry)
output.close()
```

Following also works but I find it less convenient to use in a prompt:

```
with open('output.txt') as output:
    output.write(gtf['mykey1'])
```

Comment: Thanks. But there is a TypeError:  >>> output = open('output.txt', 'w')  ///
>>> output.write(gtf['mykey1''])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: expected a string or other character buffer object

Comment: Ah, then you need to put this object into string form with the `json` library. And if you want to open it again you have to use `json.loads(stringified_entry)` to create a dictionary again.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
with open("output.txt","w+") as file:
    file.write(gtf['mykey1'])
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to stringify a dict to save it to a txt in python, you CANNOT save a dict as is, without first making it either a string to save it into .txt format, or `json.dump(dict_)` it to save it as a json.

This answers your question:

```
import json
stringified_json = json.dumps(gtf['mykey1'])
output = open('output.txt', 'w')
output.write(stringified_json)
output.close()
```

json.dumps takes a dict and makes it a string.

You can later load it back to a json with:

```
import json
output = open('output.txt', 'r')
stringified_json = output.read()
stringified_json = json.loads(stringified_json)   
output.close()
```